# PCB Layout DRC warning

Tags: capacitor, pcb, pcb-design, schematics, kicad

I designed my own Layout in Kicad, but after running the DRC there are some warnings. Does anyone know what is wrong with the layout? (More info in the attached images). I thought the net describes the wiring between the terminals, but as far as i know the wiring is correct?

Thats my first PCB so please be gentle :)

[image: given warning in schematic parity]

That's the given warning in 'schematic parity'

[image: PCB Layout]

That's the described part of the Pcb

[image: schematic]

That's the schematic

Comment: Did you update the PCB from the schematics?

Comment: This solved the warnings! Thank you! So the pcb "had a old schematic version in mind"? @LiorBilia

Comment: DRC is there to keep you honest.

Comment: DRC is there so you will not have to trace all your netlist on transparent sheets and verify that the layout matches the schematics.